# Installing LAMP - PHP not connecting with MySQL - Why?

Tags: 14.04, apache2, php, mysql, lamp

Am followoing this amazingly simple LAMP tutorial
http://ubuntuserverguide.com/2014/06/how-to-install-lamp-in-ubuntu-server-14-04-lts.html

- Installing Apache
- Installing MySQL
- Installing PHP

The **PROBLEM** is:

- When I check on my brower localhost/phpmysql.php
- I just see BLANK PAGE
- If the php had been runned i should see either CONGRATULATIONS or
  ERROR message back.

> ```
>  <?php
>     $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","passwordxxxxxx");
>     if (!$con)
>     {
>      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
>     }
>     else
>     {
>      echo "Congrats! connection established successfully";
>     }
>     mysql_close($con);
>   ?>
> ```

Is there any error on this PHP code maybe? 
For example: if the password is wrong setup on the PHPMYSQL.PHP file I should get back and ERROR MESSAGE couse i have a ECHO.

Why am getting a blank response? any idea of some workaround?
Thanks

Comment: Is the page failing to load, or is it 200 OK? You can check this by doing a Ctrl-Shift-C (on chromium) and clicking on the Network tab and then refreshing the page. Tell us what's under 'status' column for 'localhost/phpmysql.php' under Name?

Comment: 500
Internal Server Error

Thans for showing up, any idea where de problem comes from?

Comment: Okay. So that means your server is not set up properly. Can you give us the lines that appear in `/var/log/apache2/error.log`? 

Just say in a terminal: `less +F /var/log/apache2/error.log` (if permission error, prefix `sudo`). Now in browser, refresh the page. Copy paste the new lines that came up in the terminal in something like [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) and post the link here.

Comment: Ok,
Here is the error.log

http://pastebin.com/jGNXbFgA

Comment: You should now be able to figure out why the `missing mysqli` error is coming. If you can't, can you also pastebin your full `phpmysql.php`?

Comment: thanks for your time, but suddenly its working again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could find a solution for your problem by searching [here](https://www.google.co.in/?q=mysqli+class+not+found) based on the error in the logs.

You were missing the php's Mysqli class. Installing MyPHPAdmin (PHPMyAdmin rather) installed mysqli as a side effect, i'm guessing.

Comment: I totally agree, really interesting methodology

Answer (score 0):

ok after I installed MyPHPAdmin it is working suddendly the PHP file, and i get back all the time: Connected successfully

So I appreciate you time and your ideas!

Answer (score 0):

I know that you are looking to just connect and may just be getting started, but please stop using `mysql_connect`; I didn't even know it was still even supported at this point
A quick reference point to start with PDO is http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

A quick example of what I use for my PDO connection

I have a file. We'll call it connection.php

```
<?php

    class DDB extends pdo{


    public $sitedb = '';
    public $siteconfig;
    public $sitesettings = array(
        'host'      => "localhost",
        'database'  => "yourdb",
        'username'  => "youruser",
        'password'  => "yourpass",
    );

    public function __construct(){

        $this->db = new PDO(
            "mysql:host={$this->sitesettings['host']};" .
            "dbname={$this->sitesettings['database']};" .
            "charset=utf8",
            "{$this->sitesettings['username']}",
            "{$this->sitesettings['password']}"
        );

        $this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

    }
```

Now you could also have a new class. Let's call it accounts.php
So within accounts.php

```
<?php

    require_once("connection.php");

class Accounts() {
         public $db;
         public function __construct() {
               $this->db = new DDB();
         }

         public function GetAccountNames() {
                $query = <<<SQL
                SELECT username
                FROM accounts
SQL;
         $resource = $this->db->db->prepare( $query );
         $resource->execute();
         foreach($resource as $row) {
         echo $row['username'];
         }
     }
```

Now say you have users.php

```
<?php $accounts = new Accounts();
           $accounts->GetAccountNames();
       ?>
```

The user.php page would now loop through all the results of your accounts database. I know it's not much, but hopefully it's a good starting point to get you away from the deprecated function.